# show messages from a specific phone

Tags: android

I developed an application that is intended to communicate with a phone named A. For example, when my application receives messages from A, he shows a Toast but when it is not Who sent the message, it ignores the message received. But when I get messages, the application displays nothing. Whether it's A or someone else. I recorded the number in memory A and I get it in the application:

(It works with two emulators but it does not work with my application) ..

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    String recipient_receive;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //Récupère de la mémoire le n° du destinataire & le place dans une variable
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String recipient_number = preferences.getString("recipientNumberKey", null);

        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                //str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();    //permet de rajouter le destinataire du SMS reçu                 
                //str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";     

                recipient_receive = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            }
            if(recipient_receive.equals(recipient_number))
            {
                //---display the new SMS message---
                Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }             
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the value of `recipient_number`?

Comment: @BinyaminSharet Yes, like i said, it's working in my emulators but not in my application -.-

Comment: Does your receiver gets called at all? what block doesn't it enter? (on phone, not emulator)

Comment: recipient_number is from your view list then show toast.. simple. if you have list of user(for whom you want to show toast). then check recipient_number exist in your list then show toast..